# How do I go about separating a window to remove the grids?

Tags: repair, windows

I'm in the process of building a green house and I have a pile of windows that are brand new that have internal grids and a pile of windows that do not. I want to remove the grids so everything matches. Can I drill a hole and let the gas out then saw them apart or drill a hole to let the gas out then make that hole bigger, use a rod and pull the grids apart and seal that hole back up?

Comment: Pictures of the windows?

Comment: You'll be better served to leave the grids (and leave the windows sealed) if they are inside sealed window units as your question implies.

Comment: Here is a picture.  https://photos.app.goo.gl/S5E5zsnk2FYdhUZw5

Comment: I know I am better served leaving them. Just looking for options.  I technically don't even have to remove them. Just break them loose so they fall to the bottom. The lower foot of the window won't be seen.  If I were to drill a small hole, insert a wire coat hanger, knock the grids to the bottom and close up the hole. Will these windows forever fog and get condensation?

Comment: I have also thought of using a vacuum pump to pull any air out of the windows before plugging the hole up.  Not sure if this would matter much.

Comment: If you break the seal, the windows will fog up on the inside, eventually leading to mould. They're not vacuum-sealed, they have an inert gas between the panes. If you absolutely need to remove the decorative bars, get a double glazing company to do it & re-seal them afterwards.

Comment: Windows sometimes have a gas such as nitrogen or a rare gas. To be Frank, this is not a good idea. If you want to match them, put glazing bars on the outside on other windows.  Also, please edit your question to post photos and more info.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and use the built in image hosting to embed the picture in the question itself. Comments can and do get deleted, in which case your picture might go missing.

Comment: For clarification, is this a “greenhouse” (a place where people grow plants) or a “green house” (a house built with a goal of energy/resource efficiency)? If it’s the latter, you should be very concerned about ruining the (admittedly limited) insulative value of the windows.

Comment: Maybe do the math on how much force a double-pane window would have to endure if there was vacuum between the panes.   Hint: what is atmospheric pressure?  Can you realistically see a sheet of glass that size enduring that much force?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I drill a hole and let the gas out then saw them apart or drill a hole to let the gas out then make that hole bigger, use a rod and pull the grids apart and seal that hole back up?

**Absolutely!!**

It's probably not a good idea, though.

Your windows are sealed at the factory, either with a vacuum between the panes or an inert gas inserted after the vacuum has been drawn. Breaking the seal will let the gas out (as you know), but it will allow air in. That air will condense inside, leading to fogging. It could also start growing mold or other nasty stuff. Even if it doesn't grow mold the fogged window will not pass as much light as you'd like, and any mold, moss or other things that do decide to grow in there will block even more light from getting into your greenhouse.

Factory seals fail, which is one of the reasons why good companies warranty their windows against this. Even with a factory warranty, you'll still see houses with fogged windows because the seals failed. Even if you manage to succeed in drawing a vacuum in the windows and seal it yourself, your seal will fail fairly quickly in comparison to the factory seals and you'll be dealing with all the drawbacks sooner rather than later.

---

Since you've got some windows with grids that you don't want, I see a couple of options that *I* think would be better:

- Return the mullioned windows to the store to exchange them for ones without. (Presumes the windows were recently purchased and within a valid return period.)
- Make use of the existing stock, using mullioned windows on one side and non-mullioned windows on the other. At least each side will be consistent.
- Sell the windows with mullions (using any of the myriad of on-line, social marketing sites) and buy more without mullions. You may end up losing some money in the process. You have to decide if it's worth it to get to your final goal.
- Don't use "windows" at all, but use polycarbonate sheets like most (modern) greenhouses use.

Comment: Or: Donate the mullioned windows to a charity like Habitat For Humanity, who can use them or resell them, and take a tax deduction based on their Fair Market Value. (If they're brand new, unaltered, and still in original packaging FMV is your purchase price. For old stuff, my usual solution is to look at recent Completed Sales of similar items on eBay; the typical price people willingly pay is by definition a fair market price.)

Comment: Excellent addition, @keshlam. Unfortunately, for most folk itemizing deductions on taxes is a losing proposition these days.

Comment: All the windows that have been collected were free.  One side is completely grid free, the other would be completely gridded. So I was on the same idea path as you so far.  Because I like to diy everything, and usually can figure out what's needed, this diy has me concerned.   Final thought.  Drill hole, remove grids, get a cylinder of argon from welding shop, seal larger hole made, drill small hole, vacuum pump air out, pump argon in, seal small hole.

Comment: @MWIrish If you have the capabilities to do so, go for it! I'd venture to say that your resealing efforts won't last as long as factory sealing and that you'll be disappointed sooner rather than later. However, for the price of "free" for the windows, I guess you don't have much to loose. OTOH, selling the mullioned windows for _something_ gives you cash in hand to buy new ones without mullions...